# MS Access - Atomic Function

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, atomic

There are two fields which may change before my VBA function completes, and I would like a way to prevent this from happening.

I know Java has object locks, synchronization blocks, etc. that can be used to assist with this, but I haven't been able to find mention of this in MS Access.

Does anyone know of any tricks in MS Access to accomplish the same task?

---

ANSWER:

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblOptions", dbOpenTable, dbDenyWrite, dbPessimistic)
rs.Edit
pNum = rs!lastPolicyNumber
...
rs!lastPolicyNumber = pNum
rs.Update
rs.Close
```

Comment: with VBA you can call Windows API, like CreateEvent, WaitForSingleObject, etc

Comment: What is the backend, and if it is access, how might the fields change?

Comment: @John - The backend is Access, but its a function that performs as a query to get a value, performs a number of operations, and then writes values back to the DB. Two users calling the same function can cause a race condition.

Comment: @cha - It sounds like this might work if the users were on the same machines, but how would this work across machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open recordset with dbPessimistic and call .Edit at line you want to lock. So unlees you call .Update or .CancelUpdate record(page with record) will be locked.